# Добавление свойств через prototype

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Имеется `js` объект `TextFrame`. Мне необходимо его расширить, добавить методы и свойства. Методы я добавляю вот так

```
TextFrame.prototype.someMethod = function() {...}
```

все экземпляры объекта `TextFrame` будут иметь метод `someMethod`, все ок. Теперь я хочу добавить свойство, допустим

```
TextFrame.prototype.someProperty = true
```

код выполнится, но экземпляры объекта `TextFrame` не будут иметь это свойство. 
Вопрос, почему и как можно реализовать данную идею?

Comment: всё работает: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/JWWQY/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CJrsE/

Comment: да, все верно. Работает в браузере. Но я работаю с Adobe Indesign Server. И там почему то это не работает. Отправился курить адобовские форумы

Comment: а не работает оба примера или только второй ? (когда задаем свойство уже после new() )

Comment: только второй

Comment: ну он нечестный немного, не знаю даже насколько это законно рассчитывать на изменение уже созданного объекта в результате изменения прототипа (скажем в браузере такой эффект может получиться если переменная ушла в другой процесс (webworker например) )